# Eclipse Mars running slow

Tags: eclipse, lag

I am running mac OS X El Capitan. Eclipse is running really slow. Especially the scrolling. I am using the macbook's trackpad.

Macbook retina 13" 2015 8 GB ram, intel i5 (two cores at 2.7 ghz)

Answer (score 18):

This has been driving me nuts! It seems that there is some bug in Eclipse that causes lag when redrawing editors when OS X is using "automatic scrollbars" (see your system settings).

I found that when changing this setting to always show scroll bars, then scrolling performance in Eclipse improved.

However, I like the automatic scrollbars, so I came up with this hack: fire up a terminal to write `defaults write -app Eclipse AppleShowScrollBars Always`, and now my scrollbars always show for Eclipse, but not all the other applications.

I hope this can help others out there too, until this problem receives a proper fix :-)

Comment: This does help, thanks. If you are using Spring Tool Suite: `defaults write -app STS AppleShowScrollBars Always`

Answer (score 1):

Slow scrolling for Eclipse on OS X is a known issue:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366471

Comment: how having it open for 6 years and being known issue helps ? It just shows the care of the eclipse and swt developers for mac users.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a much needed boost in scrolling, will not be exactly butter smooth though but close to it

add the following lines to eclipse.ini

```
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```